# Insert update and delete checkbox datas in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How to Insert update and delete checkbox datas in mysql database table.I need mysql query for all operations . I have only one database table for that operations. Thanks in advance

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Cricket" /> Cricket 
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Football" />Football 
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Chess" />Chess
```

Database Structure

```
ID ,NAME, AGE ,SPORTS(checkbox need to save)
```

Comment: You should have at least 2 tables to manage that. Do you need to know the queries, the models or both ?

Comment: @Glide : I need queries and models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Shef said, you need those 3 tables `user`, `sport`, `user_sport`

**user**

```
+----+----------------+-----+
| id | name           | age |
+----+----------------+-----+
|  1 | Freddy Mercury |  65 |
|  2 | Ian Gillan     |  66 |
|  . | .              |   . |
+----+----------------+-----+
```

**sport**

```
+----+----------+
| id | sport    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Cricket  |
|  2 | Football |
|  3 | Chess    |
+----+----------+
```

**user_sport**

```
+---------+----------+
| user_id | sport_id |
+---------+----------+
|       . |        . |
+---------+----------+
```

Generate the checkboxes with this php:

```
$sql = '/* Current User Sports */
SELECT
  sp.id AS "sport_id"
, sp.name As "sport"
, us.user_id AS "checked"
FROM sport AS sp
LEFT JOIN user_sport AS us ON (
  sp.id = us.sport_id
  AND user_id = '.$user_id.'
)
;';
$result = query($sql);
foreach ($result as $row) {
?>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sports[<?php echo ($row['sport_id']) ?>]" checked="checked" />
    <?php echo ($row['sport']) ?>
  </label>
<?php
}
```

That will give you this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sports[1]" checked="checked" />Cricket 
<input type="checkbox" name="sports[2]" checked="checked" />Football 
<input type="checkbox" name="sports[3]" checked="checked" />Chess
```

**The update part**

First query (Delete the values for the current $user_id):

```
DELETE FROM user_sport WHERE user_id = $user_id;
```

Second query (Insert the new values for the current $user_id):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO user_sport
  (user_id, sport_id)
VALUES
  (';
$tmp = array();
foreach ($sports as $sport_id => $void) {
  $tmp[] = "($user_id, $sport_id)"
}
$sql .= implode("\n,   ", $tmp).'
  )
;';
```

This can work for insert/update/delete

Answer (score 1):

You should change your table schema, it's not even in the 1NF, the way you have it. You should create a minimum of two tables to handle this, but I would suggest three tables, considering the fact that sports will repeat.

These would be your tables...

**users**

```
id | name | age
```

**sports**

```
id | sport
```

**user_sports**

```
user_id | sport_id
```

---

These would be the queries...

When you generate the checkboxes, you would select from the `sports` table, and as value you would put the id of the sport, not the name.

**insert** Notice for insert, you are going to use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the id of the user, which will be used on the relationship table.

```sql
INSERT INTO users(name, age) VALUES('John', 22);
INSERT INTO user_sports(user_id, sport_id) VALUES(mysql_insert_id(), 123);
```

**select** if your checkboxes will contain the id of the sport as value

```sql
    SELECT u.id user_id, u.name, u.age, s.sport
      FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_sports us
        ON u.id = us.user_id
       AND us.sport_id = 123
INNER JOIN sports s
        ON us.sport_id = s.id
```

**select** if you have the name of the sport

```sql
    SELECT u.id user_id, u.name, u.age, s.sport
      FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_sports us
        ON u.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN sports s
        ON us.sport_id = s.id
       AND s.sport = 'Football'
```

**delete**

```sql
    DELETE u, us 
      FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN user_sports AS us
        ON u.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN sports AS s
        ON us.sport_id = s.id
       AND s.sport = 'Basketball'
```

Comment: Thanks.But i need query to insert ,upadte and delete checkbox datas  in tables